# How to add mongodb service in application running inside cf?

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, cloud-foundry, bosh-deployer

I have deployed my application in cf running on vagrant machine.But my application requires mongodb .I don't know how to add.Can anyone please hep me with this.

rle0249@rle0249-Latitude-3450:~/CloudFoundry$ cf service-brokers
Getting service brokers as admin...

name   url
No service brokers found

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can provision a MongoDB service, or any other service, you need to have an appropriate service broker registered with CF. Service brokers can run anywhere, but are often BOSH-deployed along side CF and then registered to CF.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any open-source MongoDB service brokers available for CF. There is a [sample project](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/cloudfoundry-service-broker) that demonstrates building your own MongoDB service broker, but it is only a sample and is not intended to be production ready.