# How to deploy mongoDB service in Cloud Foundry on your local?

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, cloud-foundry, bosh-deployer

I want to add mongodb services to the app deployed in cf on local machine using boshl-lite.

```
rle0249@rle0249-Latitude-3450:~/CloudFoundry/cf-services-contrib-release$ cf marketplace
Getting services from marketplace in org RelevanceLab / space RLCatalyst as admin...
OK

No service offerings found
rle0249@rle0249-Latitude-3450:~/CloudFoundry/cf-services-contrib-release$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no services available, because you have no service brokers registered with CF. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492014/1299533